# How to set the center of the map with Javascript and Subgurim Maps

Tags: google-maps, subgurim-maps

I want to set the center of a map with Javascript.

I can only find some code with Markers in it, but I want the client side code for this:

```
/* Server code */
GMap1.setCenter(latlng, zoomLevel, mapType  );
```

I would like to do this (it's non working code :-))

```
<script>
    subgurim_GMap1.SetCenter(47.1, 2.3, 6)
</script>
```

Where 47.1 and 2.3 are the Lat/Lng and 6 is the Zoom level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
map.setZoom(6);
var point = new GLatLng(26.228595038041917, 50.54535984992981);
map.setCenter(point);
```

Comment: wow, that was quick!
Do you also happen to know how to get the current lat/lng and zoomlevel in javascript? Want to set a cookie with the current values, so they can go to that position later.

Comment: GMap1.getZoomLevel() or GMap2.getZoom()

Comment: and getCoordX() and getCoordY() to get the lat/long

Comment: To be even more concise, skip 'map.setZoom(6)' and just use this instead: map.setCenter(point,6);

Comment: for the clueless like me, map it's the client name of the gmap :P it could be for example foo-map